# Return first matching value/column name in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=6, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5],
                   'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5],
                   'C': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5],
                   'D': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5],
                   'E': [1, 2, 3, 3, 7,6],
                   'F': [1, 1, 3, 3, 7,6],
                   'G': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0,0]

                  },
                 index=rng)
```

A simple dataframe to help me explain:

```
df


                    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
2011-01-01 00:00:00 0   0   0   0   1   1   0
2011-01-01 01:00:00 1   1   1   1   2   1   0
2011-01-01 02:00:00 2   2   2   2   3   3   1
2011-01-01 03:00:00 3   3   3   3   3   3   0
2011-01-01 04:00:00 4   4   4   4   7   7   0
2011-01-01 05:00:00 5   5   5   5   6   6   0
```

When I filter for a value greater than 2 I get the following output:

```
df[df >= 2]

                     A  B   C   D   E   F   G
2011-01-01 00:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2011-01-01 01:00:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN 2.0 NaN NaN
2011-01-01 02:00:00 2.0 2.0 2.0 2.0 3.0 3.0 NaN
2011-01-01 03:00:00 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 3.0 NaN
2011-01-01 04:00:00 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 7.0 7.0 NaN
2011-01-01 05:00:00 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 6.0 6.0 NaN
```

For each row I want to know which column has the matching value first (working from left to right).  So on the row for `2011-01-01 01:00:00` it was row E ands the value was 2.0.

[image]

**Desired output:**

What I would like to get is a new dataframe with the first match value in a column named 'Value' and another column called "From Col" which captures the column name this came from.

If no match seen then the output from the last column (G in this case).  Thanks for any help.

```
                       "Value" "From Col"   
    2011-01-01 00:00:00    NaN  G
    2011-01-01 01:00:00    2    E
    2011-01-01 02:00:00    2    A
    2011-01-01 03:00:00    3    A
    2011-01-01 04:00:00    4    A
    2011-01-01 05:00:00    5    A
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def get_first_valid(ser):
    if len(ser) == 0:
        return pd.Series([np.nan,np.nan])

    mask = pd.isnull(ser.values)
    i = mask.argmin()
    if mask[i]:
        return pd.Series([np.nan, ser.index[-1]])
    else:
        return pd.Series([ser[i], ser.index[i]])


In [113]: df[df >= 2].apply(get_first_valid, axis=1)
Out[113]:
                       0  1
2011-01-01 00:00:00  NaN  G
2011-01-01 01:00:00  2.0  E
2011-01-01 02:00:00  2.0  A
2011-01-01 03:00:00  3.0  A
2011-01-01 04:00:00  4.0  A
2011-01-01 05:00:00  5.0  A
```

or:

```
In [114]: df[df >= 2].T.apply(get_first_valid).T
Out[114]:
                       0  1
2011-01-01 00:00:00  NaN  G
2011-01-01 01:00:00    2  E
2011-01-01 02:00:00    2  A
2011-01-01 03:00:00    3  A
2011-01-01 04:00:00    4  A
2011-01-01 05:00:00    5  A
```

PS i took a source code of the `Series.first_valid_index()` function and made a dirty hack out of it...

Explanation:

```
In [221]: ser = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 5, 7, np.nan])

In [222]: ser
Out[222]:
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    5.0
3    7.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64

In [223]: mask = pd.isnull(ser.values)

In [224]: mask
Out[224]: array([ True,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [225]: i = mask.argmin()

In [226]: i
Out[226]: 2

In [227]: ser.index[i]
Out[227]: 2

In [228]: ser[i]
Out[228]: 5.0
```

Comment: Thanks maxu! Works perfectly.  So Im trying to understand this but struggling. The mask looks for missing values.  Then the function looks for the argmin of mask so tries to find index of any NaN?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, filter values according to criterion and drop the row containing all `NaNs`. Then, use `idxmax` to return the first occurence of a `True` condition. This resembles our first series.

To create the second series, iterate over (index, value) tuple pairs of the first series and simultaneously append these locations present in the original `DF`.

```
ser1 = (df[df.ge(2)].dropna(how='all').ge(2)).idxmax(1)
ser2 = pd.concat([pd.Series(df.loc[i,r], pd.Index([i])) for i, r in ser1.iteritems()])
```

Create a new `DF` whose index pertains to that of the original `DF` and fill the missing values in *From Col* with that of it's last column name.

```
req_df = pd.DataFrame({"From Col": ser1, "Value": ser2}, index=df.index)
req_df['From Col'].fillna(df.columns[-1], inplace=True)
req_df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with pandas, so this can be considered just as a footnote, but in pure python there is also possibility to find first non-`None` index using `reduce`.

```
>>> a
[None, None, None, None, 6, None, None, None, 3, None]

>>> print( reduce(lambda x, y: (x or y[1] and y[0]), enumerate(a), None))
4
```